# iText7 and C#, put a filled shape in a table cell

Tags: c#, .net, itext7

I am trying to add a rectangle with rounded borders in a cell of a table, created with iText7 and C#.

I tried using

`table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(rect)`

where i created `rect` with

```
Rectangle boundingBox = new Rectangle(20, 470, 30, 30);
PdfFormXObject xObject = new PdfFormXObject(boundingBox);
xObject.MakeIndirect(pdfDoc); //Make sure the XObject gets added to the document
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.AddNewPage());
Color greenColor = new DeviceCmyk(100, 30, 100, 0);
canvas.SetFillColor(greenColor);
canvas.Rectangle(294, 780, 50, 35);
canvas.FillStroke();

Image rect = new Image(xObject);
```

suggested from a friend of mine, but I think this is the wrong way to do this, and I'm not even quite sure of what this code does. Plus, the rectangle is transparent, has big margins, and the font in the cells is now green too (it was black before inserting the rectangle).

Here is how it looks like (i purposedly put the square a little bit higher to show the transparency):

[image]

What I want to do is to create a green shape rectangle, round the borders, then put it in the cell.

It should look like this:

[image]

Is there a good way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a block-level layout object (`Div`) and set all the necessary visual properties to it. It is not necessary to perform custom drawing operations. Here is the code sample (in Java, but converting to C# boils down to capitalizing method names):

```
Div rectangle = new Div()
        .setHeight(30)
        .setWidth(30)
        .setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.GREEN)
        .setBorderRadius(new BorderRadius(5))
        .setBorder(new SolidBorder(ColorConstants.GREEN, 1));

table.addCell(new Cell().add(rectangle));
```

Visually the result looks like this: [image: result]

Comment: Thanks a lot! While you were answering I tried with a `new Cell` , but I think `new Div` Makes a lot more sense!

Comment: just a small question: do you know why the div has those "transparent" borders if I do not set `.setBorder(new SolidBorder(ColorConstants.GREEN, 1));` ? Ithought it would take all the space just using the same `setHeight` as the cell, but does not happen.

Comment: I think that's because cells have paddings by default

Comment: Similarly, is there a easy way to add a circle/ellipse to the cell?